# using python how to find a element and print its index of csv file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a csv file with below matrix like information. By giving it as a input in that there is a element `-1`. I need a code to find the index of `-1`. Please help me in this.
The below data is the csv file input to python:

[image: img]

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
csv = pd.read_csv(r'C:/.../file.csv', ';')
index = []

for i,r in csv.iterrows():
      index.append(i)

print(index[-1])
```